# Change the style of an ListBox in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to change the style of an ListBox, because in WinRT the ListBox have a light background after selecting an item. But I want that the ListBox is still with an transparent background after selecting an item. How can I do this? I don't want to change an ListBoxItem, because there everything is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the ListBox, select Edit Template -> Edit a Copy.

Navigate to the Border inside `<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">`.  Select the Background Property, click the Advanced Options square, select Reset.  You can now set the background to whatever you want.